# Should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, support

I found no reason why this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/92919/11550)  is closed. This question asks whether a given phrase is the right usage for expressing a particular action. It is a particular doubt that may arise in a non-native English speakers mind. No body commented efficiently why this question should be closed. Only a single comment says *It has no real answer*. I can not see how it can not have a real answer. It has already got a lot of good quality answer. A lot of avid users of this site also argues this question should not be closed. Hence I request everybody to consider reopening this question.

Comment: I've voted to reopen and there's already one other re-open vote.

Comment: I'm becoming more familiar with this usage of *doubt*, but it still trips me up a bit.

Comment: It is now open again.